# I need to keep pressing EN on ESP32 custom board after restoring power so it can work

Tags: esp32, hardware

I've noticed that whenever i unplug the power supply on my board and plug it again, i need to press the EN button so it can start working again, knowing that i've tried 100nF, 2,2uF and 10uF on C4 capacitor.
Do i need to change the R1 resistor to a higher value ?
Here's the used schematics for the esp32 part :

update : i changed R1 to 12k and it's still the same.

Update 2 : i added a 10k resistor between the 3v3 and boot pin , solved the problem.
[image]

Comment: Are you ensuring that GPIO 0, 5, and 15 are HIGH during boot and GPIO 2 and 12 are low during boot?  https://lastminuteengineers.com/esp32-pinout-reference/

Comment: Remove C5, it fakes a boot button press at startup.

Comment: @Jens usually it works fine with that capacitors

Answer (score 0):

Add a diode over R1 in parallel so the capacitor can discharge very quickly and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: How can adding a diode make it discharge faster if i may ask ?

Comment: You put the cathode of the diode on the 3V3 and the capacitor can discharge over the load attached to 3V3 and GND.

Comment: I added a10k resistor between 3v3 and the boot pin , it solved my problem. Thank you for sharing your advices !